# Encrypting private keys in puppet template file

Tags: yaml, puppet

I have a file with one private and public key in puppet .Its a template(.erb) basically and the content consists of one public and private key.Is there any way i can encrypt the keys before pushing to r10k control repo.

Eyaml i have used for encrypting passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Encrypt first you cert,key bundle with  a password (using openssl or whatever) and store the eyaml encrypted password in your hiera.

Just be careful to the level of security you want puppet might expose your password if you don't handle it carefully.